# Proving $\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\cot30^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\cot30^\circ}=\tan 120^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

What's the way  to prove this identity?
$$\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\cot30^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\cot30^\circ}=\tan 120^\circ$$
I know this must be related to the double angle formula, but I can't find a way to rearrange the denominator.

Comment: Take the definition of $\tan$ and $\cot$ if it is very simple for you: $\tan(\pi/3)=\sqrt3$,  $\tan(\pi/6)=\sqrt3/3$ and $\cot(\pi/6)=\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Where did you get it? The denominator is no other than $1-1$ since $\tan 30=\frac 1{\tan 60}$.

Comment: I believe you mean 
$$\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\cot30^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\cot30^\circ}=\tan 120^\circ$$ (Note the cotangent in the denominator.) In that case, use fact that cotangent is the cofunction of tangent.

Comment: Plane Trigonometry
Book by Fred Winchell Sparks and Paul Rees

Comment: Yeah, I meant that, sorry for the wrong presentation.

Answer (score 3):

The "co-" in cotangent is short for *complementary* -- that is, the tangent of an angle is equal to the complementary tangent (cotangent) of the complementary angle.  As such, we can write $$\cot30^\circ=\tan(90^\circ-30^\circ)=\tan60^\circ.$$

Hence, we can write
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\cot30^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\cot30^\circ}&=\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\tan60^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\tan60^\circ}\\
&=\frac{2\tan60^\circ}{1-\tan^260^\circ}\\
&=\tan(2(60^\circ))\\
&=\tan120^\circ
\end{align}
as desired.  The follows from the double angle identity for tangents $$\tan2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}.$$

---

If you like, you can resolve (evaluate) the trigonometric ratios so that you are working with algebra alone:
$$\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\cot30^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\cot30^\circ}=\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt3}{1-\sqrt3\sqrt3}=\frac{2\sqrt3}{1-3}=-\sqrt3=\tan120^\circ.$$
I believe, however, that this ignores the intention of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apply $\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$

$$\frac{\tan 60^\circ+\cot30^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\cot30^\circ}
= \frac{\tan 60^\circ+\tan 60^\circ}{1-\tan 60^\circ\tan 60^\circ}=\tan 120^\circ
$$